# Replacing Substring with another string from column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Got this DataFrame:

| Type | String | ext_id | int_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | UKidBC | 2393 | 2820 |
| 1 | UKidBC | 4816 | 1068 |
| 0 | UKidBC | 4166 | 3625 |
| 0 | UKidBC | 2803 | 1006 |
| 1 | UKidBC | 1189 | 2697 |

For each value on String column, I need to replace the substring 'id' (UK**id**BC) according to the following rule:

If `df['Type'] = 1` then replace substring 'id' with the corresponding `df['int_id']` value else replace substring 'id' with the corresponding `df['ext_id']` value.

I tried to use that line:

```
new_df.apply(lambda x: x['string'].replace(pat=['id'], 
   repl=x['int_id']) if x['Type'] == 1
   else x['string'].replace(pat=['id'],repl=x['ext_id']),axis=1)
```

Keep getting this error:

```
str.replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: that means : remove `pat=` and `repl=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same idea as yours (`apply()`, `replace()`), just modify a bit about using `replace()`.

```
new_df["String"] = new_df.apply(
    lambda row: row["String"].replace("id", row["int_id"]) if row["type"] == 1 else row["String"].replace("id", row["ext_id"]),
    axis=1
)
```

output:

> ```
>    Type    String  ext_id  int_id
> 0     1  UK2820BC    2393    2820
> 1     1  UK1068BC    4816    1068
> 2     0  UK4166BC    4166    3625
> 3     0  UK2803BC    2803    1006
> 4     1  UK2697BC    1189    2697
> ```

Comment: This works, but using `apply` with `axis=1` is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `apply`, we could use `str.split` + `np.where` to replace values according to "Type" value:

```
tmp = df['String'].str.split('id', expand=True)
df['String'] = tmp[0] + np.where(df['Type'].astype(bool), df['int_id'].astype(str), df['ext_id'].astype(str)) + tmp[1]
```

Output:

```
   Type    String  ext_id  int_id
0     1  UK2820BC    2393    2820
1     1  UK1068BC    4816    1068
2     0  UK4166BC    4166    3625
3     0  UK2803BC    2803    1006
4     1  UK2697BC    1189    2697
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your string is fixed, use `numpy.where` and vector string concatenation:

```
df['String'] = df['String'].str[:2] + np.where(df['Type'].eq(1), df['int_id'], df['ext_id']) + df['String'].str[4:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.str.extract` and `np.where`:

```
df['String'] = df['String'].str.extract(r'(?P<g0>.+)id(?P<g2>.+)').assign(g1=np.where(df['Type'] == 1, df['int_id'], df['ext_id']).astype(str)).sort_index(axis=1).agg(list, axis=1).str.join('')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Type    String  ext_id  int_id
0     1  UK2820BC    2393    2820
1     1  UK1068BC    4816    1068
2     0  UK4166BC    4166    3625
3     0  UK2803BC    2803    1006
4     1  UK2697BC    1189    2697
```

Answer (score 0):

This question honestly looks like one of those coding challenges you see.

Assuming that your dataframe variable is `new_df`:

```py
for i in new_df:
    i["string"].replace("id", i["int_id"] if i["type"] else i["ext_id"])
```

What you did wrong is (as the error says) you gave keyword arguments to `str.replace`, which does not take kwargs. Instead, the first argument is the pattern to replace, and the second is what to replace it with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `str.split()` and `where()`

```
s = df['String'].str.split('id')
df['String'] = (s.str[0] + 
 (df['ext_id'].where(df['Type'].ne(1),df['int_id'])).astype('str') + 
 s.str[-1])
```